# Prediction with positive weights?

Tags: matrices, st.statistics, stochastic-processes

Consider a covariance function (positive definite function) on $\mathbb{Z}$:
$$
\gamma(k)=(1+|k|)^{-\alpha},\quad \alpha>0.
$$
It is guaranteed to be positive definite by Polya's criterion (monotonicity and convexity). Consider matrices 
$$
\Sigma_1=[\gamma(i-j)]_{1\le i,j\le m},\quad \Sigma_2=[\gamma(k+i-j)]_{1\le i,j\le m},\quad m>0,~k\ge 0.
$$ 
**Show that all entries of $\Sigma_1^{-1}\Sigma_2$ are nonnegative.**

*Remark: I checked it numerically for different $k$, $m$ and $\alpha$. **A weaker statement involving large enough $k\asymp m^{1+\epsilon}$, where $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrarily small, is also of great interest.** A further question is to identify general conditions on a positive definite $\gamma(k)$ which fulfills the preceding requirement.*

*Remark:* The problem can be reinterpreted in terms of linear prediction of stationary time series $\{X(n)\}$ whose covariance function is $\gamma(k)$.
It is the same as to show that the linear predictor $\hat{X}(k)=\sum_{j=1}^m c_jX(j)$ which minimizes the mean square error $E |X(k)- \hat{X}(k)|^2$ satisfies $c_j\ge 0$.

Answer (score 3):

Let's rephrase the question in terms of geometry. Write 
$$v_n = (\gamma(n),\gamma(n-1),\ldots,\gamma(n-m+1))^T.$$

Then the columns of $\Sigma_1$ are just $v_0,\ldots, v_{m-1}$ and the columns of $\Sigma_2$ are $v_k, v_{k+1},\ldots, v_{k+m-1}$. Thus the columns of $M = \Sigma_1 ^{-1} \Sigma_2$ are just the coefficients by which each $v_{k+j}$ can be (uniquely) represented as a linear combination of the basis $v_0,\ldots,v_{m-1}$.

For $M = \Sigma_1 ^{-1} \Sigma_2$ to have all entries nonnegative for all $k$ is to say that each $v_k, k\in \mathbb{N}$ is representable as a nonnegative linear combination of $v_0,\ldots,v_{m-1}$.

Looking at $v_i$ as points in $\mathbb{R}^m$, the statement of the question is equivalent to saying that when we take the sequence $v_0, v_1, \ldots, $ of points, the first $m$ points together with $0$ form the convex hull of the entire sequence. We can think of the first $m$ points as forming a "convex cone" with the origin, within which all of the other points must lie in a spiral towards zero.

Using this picture we can see for any fixed $m$, all sufficiently large $k$ work. That's because $v_n/\|v_n\|\rightarrow \frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}\cdot(1,1,\ldots,1)$, and the all $1$'s vector lies in the cone. It shouldn't be difficult to give an effective bound on how large $k$ has to be from this argument.

Comment: Thank you for your nice insight! Indeed I noticed that the positiveness holds for $m$ fixed and large $k$. Ideally I need it for large enough $k\asymp m^{1+\epsilon}$, where $\epsilon>0$ is an arbitrarily small number. Do you think the potential argument works in this regime?

Comment: Interestingly, the positive definiteness is not needed anywhere in the argument, so it was a red herring?

Comment: @Suvrit In fact without positive definiteness, with $\Sigma_2$ given by a random matrix with every entry close to 1, this seems to fail numerically.

Comment: @Suvrit It does not use but it only works in the fixed m large k regime.

Comment: @Ray ah, I skipped reading the "sufficiently large $k$..."

Comment: @Ray Intuitively this argument should work for $k \gg m$, for the following reason. Suppose the cone contains a symmetric cone like $(1\pm c, 1\pm c, \ldots, 1\pm c)$ around the all 1's vector. Then, $v_k$ will run into this cone by the time the ratio between the largest and smallest coordinates of $v_k$ is less than $1+c$ or so. This ratio is essentially $1+\alpha m /(1+k)$ for $k \gg m$, using Bernoulli's inequality as an estimate, so we expect once $k \gg m$ these points will all lie in that small cone. I'm not entirely sure $c$ can be picked independent of $m$ though.

Comment: @XiaoyuHe BTW, could you give the argument that $(1,...,1)$ lies in the cone formed by the $v_0,..., v_{m-1}$.

Comment: @ray , its easy to write 1 as a positive combination of positive numbers, just multiply them by their inverse. Arrange all the vectors in a matrix and think coordinatewise

Comment: @Pushpendre Sorry I could not see this, as it is a system of equations.

Comment: Actually I still can't give a clear explanation for why $(1,\ldots,1)$ is in the cone - although I think it's certainly true. Originally I thought $\Sigma_1$ was circulant, and then it's obvious, but $\Sigma_1$ is only symmetric Toeplitz. Perhaps you can check the literature on symmetric positive definite Toeplitz matrices? I understand they're relatively easy to diagonalize.

Answer (score 0):

10 December: My semester just ended and I got to think more about this problem. This is still a work in progress, but I thought I'd share my findings.

Starting from where @Xiaoyu left, we want to prove that $\mathbf{1} = (1, \ldots, 1)^T$ lies in the convex cone spanned by $v_0, \ldots, v_{m-1}$. Let's first establish that $\Sigma_1$ simply being symmetric positive definite Topelitz is not enough.

Let $M = \begin{bmatrix}1 &  2& 5\\ 2 &  1& 2\\ 5& 2& 1\\\end{bmatrix}$

Let $\Sigma_1 = \text{sqrtm}(M^2) = \begin{bmatrix} 
 5.0464   &    1.8543 &      1.0464\\
       1.8543      &  1.457    &   1.8543\\
       1.0464    &   1.8543  &     5.0464\end{bmatrix}$

$\Sigma_1$ is toeplitz, symmetric, PD but $\Sigma_1^{-1} \mathbf{1} = (-0.19868\ 1.1921\ 
-0.19868)^T$. This means that the values in $\Sigma_1 = [\gamma_\alpha(i-j)]_{ij}$ need to be taken into account to prove that $\mathbf{1}$ lies in the convex cone.

Numerical calculations strongly suggest though that this should be true

```
>> f = @(k, alpha) all(((1 + toeplitz(0:k-1)).^-alpha)\ones(k,1)> eps);    
>> all(arrayfun(@(alpha) f(100, alpha), 0.1:0.1:5)))
1
```

So far I have only been able to *prove* this in the trivial case when $\alpha=1$. The interesting case when $\alpha \ne 1$ is still open. Applying Farkas lemma changes the problem to proving that $\nexists y \in \mathbb{R}^n: \Sigma_1y \ge 0 ,\, \mathbf{1}^Ty < 0$ which I dont see, how it would be useful.